# How to access local web server on Mac

Tags: php, mysql, macos, terminal, webserver

Using the build-in apache and mysql, I created a database using mysql in Terminal and then I imported a php file, also using Terminal.
The question is how to I access this website now in Safari? With which ip or hostname?
Using show variables; indicates that macbook-air.local is my hostname, but it doesn't load.

Any sugestions, please?

Comment: Apache needs to be running, by default it might be responding to your local ip: 127.0.0.1

Comment: If the IP address doesn't work try `http://localhost`.